# Returning an event from a function

Tags: c#, events

What is the syntax to return an event from a function? (Not to call the event, to return it so that it can be bound to functions).

I have a container class that contains a dictionary where each members has an event.

The aim is to be able to write something like this:

```
Container c = new Container();
c.CreateEventForKey("a");             // Create the member in the dictionary
c.EventForKey("a") += some_function;  // Bind some_function to the event in the "a" member
c.OnEventForKey("a","b");             // Calls some_function with argument "b"
```

The Container class looks like this:

```
public class Container {

  public class Member {
     public event Action<string> AnEvent;
     public void OnEvent( string v ) { if(AnEvent!=null) { AnEvent(v); } }
  }

  protected Dictionary<string,Member> members;

  // This seems to work OK.
  public void OnEventForKey(string k, string v) {
    if ( members.ContainsKey(k) ) { members[k].OnEvent(v); }
    else { /* report error */ }
  }

  // Can't get this to compile.
  public event Action<string> EventForKey(string k ) {
    if ( members.ContainsKey(k) ) { return members[k].AnEvent; }
    else { /* report error */ }
  }
}
```

How can I define `EventForKey` so that this does what I expect?

Comment: I don't think you can return an event, but you can return a delegate which can be bound to an event. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the event keyword from your declaration of AnEvent, as well as from the return type of EventForKey.

Comment: @IanNewson - the key part of what I'm having trouble with is the `c.EventForKey("a") += some_function;`. I'd rather write that than the cumbersome `c.members["a"].AnEvent += some_function`, (as I can add error checking and logging to the first version, but not to the second).

Comment: You can add logging to the second by creating an indexer in your container class.

Comment: @IanNewson - just removing the `event` bit generates an error like this `Operator '+' cannot be used with a left hand side of type 'function(string): void' and a right hand side of type 'function(string): void'.` when you try to make the `c.EventForKey("a") += some_function;` call.

Comment: This was an attempt to reduce code duplication in the `Container` class. Even if the ideal method had worked I would have been trading compile time errors for run time errors - So instead I'm generating the Container file and all its events from a simple template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the syntax to return an event from a function?

You can't, easily. Events - like properties - aren't really first class "objects" as such; they're members of a class. You don't really *have* a class member here - you're trying to just keep delegates in a dictionary.

You *could* create your own "event-like" container, but it's probably better to consider alternative designs, e.g.

```
c.Subscribe("a", SomeFunction);
c.OnEventForKey("a");
```

You might want to look at [`EventHandlerList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply return member and subscribe to it's event?

```
public IMember MemberForKey(string key) // return IMember
{
    if (!members.ContainsKey(key))
        throw new Exception();

    return members[key];
}
```

And then subscribe:

```
Container c = new Container();
c.CreateEventForKey("a");            
c.MemberForKey("a").AnEvent += some_function;
c.OnEventForKey("a", "b");
```

But you have public `OnEvent` method in `Member` class. In order to forbid raising events by client, you can create interface which will show only event. Just implement this interface by `Member` class:

```
public interface IMember
{
    event Action<string> AnEvent;
}
```

And yes, you cannot return event, because actually event is not object, it is set of two methods `add` and `remove`, which add and remove delegates to inner field of delegate type. Here is how your event looks like:

```
  private Action<string> _action; // field of delegate type

  public event Action<string> AnEvent
  { 
      add { _action += value; }
      remove { _action -= value; }
  }
```

Purpose of event is to provide only two operations for clients - adding and removing handlers. Delegate itself is hidden to clients. You can make it public:

```
public Action<string> _action;
```

But in this case any client can invoke it.

UPDATE: if you want to go with Subscribe/Remove syntax, then just use dictionary with handlers:

```
public class Container
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action<string>> handlers = 
            new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>();

    public void CreateEventForKey(string key)
    {
        // with empty handler added you can avoid null check
        handlers.Add(key, (value) => { });
    }

    public void OnEventForKey(string key, string value)
    {
        if (!handlers.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new Exception();

        handlers[key](value);
    }

    public void Subscribe(string key, Action<string> handler)
    {
        if (!handlers.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new Exception();

        handlers[key] += handler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's complete working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Container c = new Container();
        c.CreateEventForKey("a");             // Create the member in the dictionary
        c.EventForKey("a").Add(str => Console.WriteLine(str));
        c.EventForKey("a").Add(str => Console.WriteLine(str.ToUpper()));
        c.OnEventForKey("a", "baa baa black sheep");

        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Container
    {

        public class Member
        {
        public List<Action<string>> AnEvent = new List<Action<string>>();
        public void OnEvent(string v)
        {
            if (AnEvent != null)
            {
                this.AnEvent.ForEach(action => action(v));
            }
        }

        public void AddEvent(Action<string> action)
        {
            this.AnEvent.Add(action);
        }
    }

    protected Dictionary<string, Member> members = new Dictionary<string,Member>();

    public void CreateEventForKey(string key)
    {
        this.members[key] = new Member();
    }

    // This seems to work OK.
    public void OnEventForKey(string k, string v)
    {
        if (members.ContainsKey(k)) { members[k].OnEvent(v); }
        else { /* report error */ }
    }

    public List<Action<string>> EventForKey(string k)
    {
        if (members.ContainsKey(k)) { return members[k].AnEvent; }
        else { throw new KeyNotFoundException(); }
    }
}
```

The difference is to behave similarly to an event by using a list of delegates.